# Повторное введение данных, пока не введут верные и не получится результат

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сделать так, если решения не существует (т.е. Impossible), то предложить снова ввести A, B, C.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

long long byaka(long long a, long long b, long long& k, long long& w)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        k = 1;
        w = 0;
        return a;
    }
    long long d = byaka(b, a % b, k, w);
    k -= (a / b) * w;
    swap(k, w);
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    long long a, b, c, k, w, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    d = byaka(a, b, k, w);
    if (c % d == 0)
    {
        long long t = c / d * k, t2 = b / d;
        if (t == 0)cout << 0 << " " << c / d * w;
        if (t > 0)cout << t + t2 * (-(t / t2)) << " " << c / d * w - a / d * (-(t / t2));
        if (t < 0)cout << t + t2 * (-((t - t2 + 1) / t2)) << " " << c / d * w - a / d * ((-((t - t2 + 1) / t2)));
    }
    else cout << "Impossible";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы можете просто создать цикл, в котором проверяется являются ли введённые данные неверными и если да, то выполнить итерацию цикла с вводом новых данных. В  вашем случае это будет так:

```
int main() {
    long long a, b, c, k, w, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    d = byaka(a, b, k, w);
    while (c % d != 0) {
        cout << "Impossible. Enter again: ";
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        d = byaka(a, b, k, w);
    }
    long long t = c / d * k, t2 = b / d;
    if (t == 0)cout << 0 << " " << c / d * w;
    if (t > 0)cout << t + t2 * (-(t / t2)) << " " << c / d * w - a / d * (-(t / t2));
    if (t < 0)cout << t + t2 * (-((t - t2 + 1) / t2)) << " " << c / d * w - a / d * ((-((t - t2 + 1) / t2)));
}
```

Comment: при вводе 0 0 1 все ломается и пишет - Исключение не обработано. Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6264825ED в Project7.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.

Comment: @Feldmanjoe так это уже ваша ошибка. На вопрос я ответил. Исключение вызвано тем, что вы делите н а ноль (когда проверяете делимость `c` на `d`). Что с этим делать, решайте сами.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь попробовать просто засунуть код в while(true) {}